# Embed Power BI Report in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, powerbi, adal

I am Trying to embed a Power BI report in an HTML page, now I know how to create the basic code to embed the report in an iframe using javascript, but the problem is that I could not automate the process to generate and refresh the access token in the backend. I was considering making the authentication process using ADAL JS. Anyone has experience in this?, or if someone have any other solution is welcome. Excuse my little knowledge but I am not a developer
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Refresh-token-using-JavaScript-SDK-example

You can create the token via ADAL.js, or any other AJAX\HTTP libraries

```js
function embedReportAndSetTokenListener(setAccessToken = false, 
    reportId, 
    groupId, 
    datasetId, 
    accessLevel, 
    baseUri, 
    embedUrl) {
    // Generate embed token
    generateEmbedToken(reportId, groupId)
    .then(function( Token ) {
        var embedToken = Token.token;
        
        // set config for embedding report
        var config = createConfig(embedToken,embedUrl,reportId);
        
        // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
        var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
        
        // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
        var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
        
        // Report.off removes a given event handler if it exists.        
        report.off("loaded");

        // Report.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.
        report.on("loaded", function() {
        // Set token expiration listener
        setTokenExpirationListener(Token.expiration,
        2 /*minutes before expiration*/, 
        reportId, 
        groupId);
        });
    });
}

function setTokenExpirationListener(tokenExpiration, 
    minutesToRefresh = 2, 
    reportId, 
    groupId){
    // get current time
    var currentTime = Date.now();
    var expiration = Date.parse(tokenExpiration);
    var safetyInterval = minutesToRefresh* 60 * 1000;

    // time until token refresh in milliseconds
    var timeout = expiration - currentTime - safetyInterval;

    // if token already expired, generate new token and set the access token
    if (timeout<=0)
    {
        console.log("Updating Report Embed Token");
        updateToken(reportId, groupId);
    }
    // set timeout so minutesToRefresh minutes before token expires, token will be updated
    else 
    {
        console.log("Report Embed Token will be updated in " + timeout + " milliseconds.");
        setTimeout(function() {
        updateToken(reportId, groupId);
        }, timeout);
    }
}

function updateToken(reportId, groupId) {
    // Generate new EmbedToken
    generateEmbedToken(reportId, groupId)
    .then(function( Token ) {
        // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
        var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

        // Get a reference to the embedded report.
        var report = powerbi.get(embedContainer);

        // Set AccessToken
        report.setAccessToken(Token.token)
        .then(function() {
        // Set token expiration listener
        // result.expiration is in ISO format
        setTokenExpirationListener(Token.expiration,2 /*minutes before expiration*/);
        });
    });
}
```